# How to have a has_one with an alias in Rails 4+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, activemodel

I have the current model structure

```
publisher
---------
has_many :digest_templates
has_one :active_template

digest_templates
---------
belongs_to :publisher, optional: true
```

The database structure is:

```
publishers
---------
t.string :name
t.string :permalink
t.string :api_key
t.string :domain
t.reference :digest_template, index: true, foreign_key: true

digest_templates
---------
t.text :html
t.text :text
t.references :publisher, index: true, foreign_key: true
t.boolean :global, default: false # this is for internally developed templates
```

At any given time, a publisher can have one active template but can create any number of custom templates for themselves. I want to make it so that the following calls are possible:

`Publisher.templates` and `Publisher.active_template`

The main issue is that I have global templates and user created templates in the same table. Is it possible to make it work with this architecture? Or is there a better way of doing things?

Comment: An active template would also be a digest template at the same time? If so, you are saving the same data twice in the database.

Comment: @ArslanAli The active_template is just an ID reference to the digest_template that's active.

Comment: It seems like this will work. What is the problem are you encountering? What should `publisher.templates` return? Should it simply return all of the association `digest_templates` from the `has_many` relationship?

Comment: How are you specifying the active template?

Answer (score 1):

Several issues:

1. You don't need `t.references :digest_template` in your `publishers` table (if it's `has_many`, all the foreign keys will be in the associated table, which [you've got already](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association))
2. You've not defined whether a template is "active" or not in the db

---

The biggest problem I see is there's no way to define whether a template is "active". I would add a bool column to your `publishers` table called `active`:

```
# db/migrate/add_active_to_templates______.rb
class DigestTemplate < ActiveRecord::Migration
    change_table :templates do |t|
       t.boolean :active, default: :false
    end
end
```

The pattern you have is that a `template` `belongs_to` `publisher`, which gives you a scope to work with. The question then becomes how you define which of your templates is "active".

The solution I would use is as follows:

```
#app/models/digest_template.rb
class DigestTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :publisher
   validates :active, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
   scope :active, -> { where active: true }
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
#app/models/publisher.rb
class Publisher < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :digest_templates

   def active_template
      digest_templates.find_by active: true 
   end
end
```

--

Your question was slightly wrong in the sense that you wouldn't be able to call `Publisher.active_template`, as that's a *class* method.

You'd have to do the following:

```
@publisher = Publisher.find params[:id]
@publisher.digest_templates #-> returns all (including active)
@publisher.active_template  #-> returns only active
```

Comment: Just like was the case with Arslan this is mostly right except for the fact that there are globally accessible templates (where `global` is set to true). These are the default templates accessible to ALL users. So simply setting `active` to true wouldn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For the simplest case, I'd say to add a column `active` of type `boolean` in `digest_templates`, and add a validation like:

```
validate_uniqueness_of :active, if: :active_template?
```

With this line of code, you can have only one template with `active` equal to `true` at one time. It will save you one table.

Now, you would need to define only a single relationship like `has_many :templates`, and you can define instance methods to get the active template.

Comment: This doesn't work when the publisher has the default template as global. They don't own that template so there's no way to tell.

Comment: So a template belongs to a user in two ways: 1) A user can be the owner of the that template; 2) A user can have that template as his default template. Right?

Comment: yes. However there's one other thing: when a user is first generated they are assigned a default template which is called `global` (in other words it's accessible to all users)